# Rename and move Repo folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, rename

What is the best practise for renaming and relocating a physical repo folder? (single user using local HDD for repo)

I need to do this as I have verified that backing up my local Tortoise SVN repository via the [svnadmin method](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-backup.html) fails due to my folder/filename naming convention containing spaces.

disclosure: SVN newb.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just use correct syntax for path-with-spaces

   > svnadmin dump "z:\My Test Repostory" > c:\repodump.dmp
   >
   > - Dumped revision 0.
   > - Dumped revision 1.
   > - Dumped revision 2.
   > - Dumped revision 3.

and repodump.dmp contains full, correct dump

1. If you use file:/// protocol for accessing local repository, movement repository to the new location and using **new repository** in **old Working Copy** is easy task:

   - Copy (and rename, if needed) folder of repository in new arbitrary new place. Repository directory is directory with the same `dir` output as below

   > dir /B "My Test Repostory"

`locks`

`hooks`

`conf`

`README.txt`

`db`

`format`

`svn.ico`

- Relocate old Working Copy for using new repository-URL